# SQL Server: Replace special character only when preceded by alpha

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm attempting to create a function that takes in a string and replaces all instances of `[alpha character]"` with `[alpha character] Inch`. For instance, the string `4" sticker` becomes `4 Inch sticker`, but the string `My "Loving" Brother` remains unchanged.

I know I can replace directly using `REPLACE(@String, '"', ' Inch')`, but that wouldn't leave the second example unchanged. How can I replace this special character only when the preceding value is an alpha (a-Z) value?

I appreciate any assistance!

Comment: "All Instances"  so if you had `4"x2" sticker book`  nothing would change?  So really, you only want to change the value if it occurs just once?  Rule is too open for ambiguity in my book.  Maybe... http://rextester.com/IFC94069 but it only handles 1 `Case when len(src)-len(replace(src,'"','')) = 1 then replace(src,'"',' Inch ')
else 
  src
end`

Comment: That's correct. It would definitely be nice to account for edge cases like your example, but I think if I understand how to accomplish the simple case, I can probably figure out how to build out the rest. I didn't want to waste anymore of your (or anyone else's) time than necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yet another option, which can easily be converted into a Table-Valued Function or Scalar-Valued Function

**Example**

```
Declare @S varchar(max) = 'The "bid" was for 8'' 12"'

Select @S = Replace(@S,MapFrom,MapTo)
 From (
        Select MapFrom = concat(n,MapFrom)
              ,MapTo   = concat(n,MapTo)
         From (values (0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) N(N)  
         Cross Join (values ('''',' Feet'),('"',' Inch')) C(MapFrom,MapTo)          
      ) A

Select @S
```

**Returns**

```
The "bid" was for 8 Feet 12 Inch
```

**Just to aid with the Visual**

The subquery generates the following, which simply perform a series of "dynamic" replaces

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a recursive CTE, like this:

```
declare @InputString varchar(100)
set @InputString = '2"x4" picture frame "Love"'
;with a as(select convert(varchar(max),@InputString) i, convert(int, PATINDEX('%[0-9]"%', @InputString)) p
union all 
select stuff(i, p+1, 1, ' Inch') i, convert(int, PATINDEX('%[0-9]"%', stuff(i, p+1, 1, ' Inch'))) p
from a where PATINDEX('%[0-9]"%', i) > 0)
select * from a
where p = 0
```

Results:

```
2 Inchx4 Inch picture frame "Love"
```